# Etiquetas [servidor] y [servidores] deberían ser sinónimas

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Al parecer [servidores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servidores) y  [servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servidor) son lo mismo, con 162 y 230 preguntas respectivamente. Podrían ser fusionadas, ya que creo no entrega mayor valor una de la otra.

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo. De hecho, yo me cargaría la que usa plural, pues cuando uno está escribiendo "servid..." ya se sugiere [tag:servidor]. No veo necesidad de mantener plurales a menos que haya mucha diferencia en el nombre.

Comment: Gracias por la publicación Alter! Le doy un tiempo prudencial para posibles discusiones, aunque no creo que lo haya heheh

Comment: @lois6b yo ya tenía el dedo en el gatillo. Pero esperaremos un poco como dices, aunque no creo que haya oposicion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya que no había ninguna objeción, he realizado la fusión de las etiquetas, dejando [servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servidor) como la principal.